# Sublinear algorithm to find the maximum contiguous range with elements >= k in an array

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

You are given an array `A` of length `N` containing natural numbers.
The question is: Give an index `i` and a natural number `k`, what is the maximum offset `m` such that all elements in the subarray `A[i,i+m]` are greater or equal to `k`.

There is a trivial O(N) algorithm: Start at `i` and scan the array to the right until you hit an offset with `A[i+m] < k`.

What I am looking for is an algorithm and a datastructure such that:

- The datastructure can be computed from the given array in at most O(N log N)
- The size of the datastructure is at most O(N)
- The algorithm uses the precomputed datastructure to solve the problem described above in at most O(log N).

Can anyone construct such an algorithm? Or is there a good argument why such an algorithm cannot exist?

The best thing I could come up with involves a O(N²) datastructure constructed in O(N²) and O(log N) lookup.

Comment: sort the array with heap sort or merge sort, search for the upper bound, what structure did you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use a special data structure that can be constructed in linear time and answers a range maximum query in `O(1)`. It is rather complex, you can read about it [here](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor). When we have this data structure, we can use binary search to find the largest feasible `m`. It requires `O(log N)` time per query.

Comment: it says: `This takes O(N logN) time and space`. therefore it violates the second requirement

Comment: @piotrek I have fixed the link. I referred to the entire article, which describes an `O(N), O(1)` solution for rmq in the end. The rest of the article is helpful for understanding how it works.

Comment: This is actually pretty brilliant!